# How to re-route existing path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I got a closed path A on one hand and on the other hand I have a path B made of 2 anchor points.

I would like to pick an anchor point in path A and make it that the next anchor in the path is one of the anchor in path B, then it continues to the second anchor in B and then it comes back to what was the next anchor in path A.

The handles from B would have to be preserved.

Comment: You'll have to do this manually by cutting then joining anchors from B.

Comment: I'm trying but how to use the scissor tool to cut a path between two anchors ? And then how to join ?

Comment: [**Start here**](https://www.google.com/search?q=basic+adobe+illustrator+tutorials&safe=off&hl=en&biw=1209&bih=1388&site=imghp&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=7aj7VOaNLYabyAS_woGIDQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAA&dpr=1)

Comment: so in a way you want to combine path a and path b into a big path, let's call it c?

Comment: @Naty yes exactly but I want to be able to chose where I insert B in A. I managed to do it but I'm not sure how if I'm confronted to it again and succeed in redoing it I'll post an answer.

Comment: What do you mean where? each stroke has 2 edges, you cannot connect it to a random part of the stroke and split it.